# Removing spaces between lines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm just learning JavaScript, and I've come up with the following page that "draws" a guitar fretboard by creating a 6X16 grid of images (the first column is the set of "open notes" on the very left hand side of the image grid). The page is [here](http://simplestuff.azurewebsites.net/scales.cshtml).

Each of the six rows represents a string on the guitar so, six strings, six rows. But what I can't figure out is how to make the rows butt up right next to each other, with no whitespace between the top of one row and the bottom of the next. So, what I get is this:

[image]

But what I want is this:

[image]

The way that the JavaScript works is to run through a loop that is 16 items long - one "open string" image, and 15 "fretted note" images, and at the end of the loop it generates a `<br/>`tag. These strings are inserted into an InnerHTML value of a `<p>` element, and the grid of images gets drawn. Here is the line of code that generates, as an example, the fretted note image:

```
for(frets=0; frets < 17; frets++){
        GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML = GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML + "<img title=" + allNotes[frets + 1] + " src=images\\" + allFretImages[frets + 1] + ">";
        continue;
    }
```

What I don't understand is:

1. What CSS attribute/value pairs do I need to enter to get the images 
   to not have any space between them above and below,and
2. How do I write the JavaScript code to add those CSS attribute/value pairs to the  tag in my code?

Add'l information:

I have tried, as an example, to write the following code in my JS file:

```
GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML = GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML + "<img title=" + allNotes[frets + 1] + " style=padding:0px; margin:0px;" + " src=images\\" + allFretImages[frets + 1] + ">";
```

But this produces the following HTML output:

```
<img title="F.Esharp.Gbb" style="padding: 0px;" src="images\F.jpg" margin:0px;="">
```

So the first problem is specifically around JS syntax and how I need to craft the code statement to generate multiple attribute/value pairs for the style tag, and the second is which CSS tags I should use to get my desired results.

Thanks in advance, and please feel free to let me know what additional information I can provide.

Comment: Apparently, at least two people will. One of them has actually given me something to investigate, and the other has provided me truly meaningful feedback regarding the length and quality of my question. I'm open to actionable feedback, but if three short paragraphs and two bulleted, specific questions, are too much for you to read, I would respectfully request that you ignore the question and move on.

Comment: Play with `line-height`.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Use this `GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML = GuitarNeckImg.innerHTML + "<img title=" + allNotes[frets + 1] + " style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;" src=images\\" + allFretImages[frets + 1] + ">";`. It helps you to remove the spaces.

Comment: @Cerbrus, thanks - I did provide some code, and I read the link you provide but, to be honest, I'm not quite sure what else I can provide that would improve on the information in that link. That said, I'm not complaining here, I appreciate the input/feedback, but not quite sure how I can act on. And, <I>that said</>, I'll play around with some of the answers some other responders have provided and follow up to this thread to let everyone know the results.

Comment: @torazaburo - thank you very much, I'll play around with your answers and let you know what the results are.

Comment: @alireza - thank you very much, I'll play around with your answers and let you know what the results are.

Comment: @Chris: a [mcve]. That means an example that reproduces the problem in the question.

Comment: Don't add that much code in comments... Not readable at all...

Comment: @Cerbrus - understood. I've deleted those two comments and updated my original question with add'l JS code and HTML output information - thanks for your help and your patience

Comment: Not about all this "complete and verifiable example" stuff in this particular case. It's very easy to figure out what is going on, and very easy to figure out how to fix it (`line-height: 0.7`).

Comment: @torazaburo - THANK YOU! - I couldn't actually get this to work in my JS code, but I added it to my CSS file, and it worked beautifully! Thank you again, really appreciate the help. Is there some way that I can mark this as an answer? I selected the option to say that this was helpful but since it solved my problem, I'd like to give it the recognition it deserves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appropriate `line-height` value, such as 0.70, should do exactly what you want.

Comment: It does indeed - thanks again, really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
//We define the text variable that needs to be cleansed of line breaks.
Var someText = "Here's some text.\n It has some line breaks that will be removed \r using Javascript.\r\n";

//This javascript code removes all 3 types of line breaks
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Best of luck...

Comment: This is not what the OP needs/wants to do.

Comment: That is not at all what the OP is trying to do.